# One route works but not other two (using AngularJS and RouteProvider)

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

AngularJS v1.7.4

I am new to AngularJS and creating a simple app but not sure why one route works (shows the static html from a partial file as well as `{{message}}` correctly), but the other two routes only show static html and not `{{message}}` which is being set using `$scope.message`.

Additionally errors such as

> The controller with the name 'ContactController' is not registered.

and

> The controller with the name 'AboutController' is not registered.

Are seen in the console when trying to go to 'Contact' and 'About' pages respectively.

For the three routes I have three html files and three controller files. I have made sure to include `<body ng-app="gmsApp">`.

Files are being loaded as

```
<script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="./js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="./js/controllers/about.controller.js"></script>
<script src="./js/controllers/contact.controller.js"></script>
<script src="./js/controllers/home.controller.js"></script>

<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
```

Following advise from other posts I am using the 'regular' js files and not 'minified' versions of angular and angular-route.

The code in main html file is:

```
    var app = angular.module("gmsApp", ['ngRoute', 'gmsApp.controllers']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }]);
```

/js/controllers/home.controller.js

```
angular.module('gmsApp.controllers', [])
.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Main page of the app';
});
```

/js/controllers/about.controller.js

```
angular.module('gmsApp.controllers', [])
.controller('AboutController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is about us page';
});
```

/js/controllers/contact.controller.js

```
angular.module('gmsApp.controllers', [])
.controller('ContactController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact Us page ...';
});
```

/partials/home.html

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <h3>Home page</h3>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

/partials/about.html

```
<div ng-controller="AboutController">
    <h3>About Us</h3>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

/partials/contact.html

```
<div ng-controller="ContactController">
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error come from the fact that you are recreating your module in each of your controller. This line should be present in only one of your files (could be your main file):

```
angular.module('gmsApp.controllers', [])
```

Then in "/js/controllers/home.controller.js,"/js/controllers/about.controller.js" and "/js/controllers/contact.controller.js", you should use it like this:

```
angular.module('gmsApp.controllers')
```

Note that this time you don't use the "[]". The difference between the two is that here you will access the already created module.

From angularjs docs:

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. Now I get a different error when I view the home page.

`Module 'gmsApp.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: `angular.module('gmsApp.controllers', [])`

Does this go in my main html file? Where exactly in the code should this be placed?

Comment: Do you have a main js file ? Like app.js ? In which you could put all of your routing and module declaration ?

Comment: No there is no app.js file. I just have the main html page. The routing is in the html page itself (inside `script` tags)

Inside the body tag I have 

`<div id="navigation">
        <a href="#!/home">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#!/about">About</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="#!/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>`

Comment: then put "angular.module('gmsApp.controllers', [])" in "about.controller.js" because it is the first included controller and "angular.module('gmsApp.controllers')" in the other two

Comment: Perfect! That worked. How do I mark it as an answer?

Comment: You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).